# How do I get the _count in my content provider?

Tags: android, count, android-contentprovider

What should I do to get my content provider to return the _count column with the count of records? The documentation says it is automatic, but maybe it's only taking about some built-in content provider. Running  a query to the database seems not to return it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are using `ContentProvider.query()` a `Cursor` is returned.  Call `Cursor.getCount()` to get a count of records in the returned cursor.

Comment: The problem with this is that it actually performs a query and allocates memory for the records, etc.  There is a better way to get count as-if the SQL statement "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE" ... I will keep looking for this alternate answer.

Comment: You can get the count without fetching all the records. See the answer below from me..

Comment: This won't let a provider support the _count column: SqliteQueryBuilder will throw an exception if you don't filter out the "_count" column from the projection.

Comment: With cursor.getCount() you can not assure that it returns the real number of items returned. There are much better ways:

1- If you are using Content Providers, you can do a query and use the Column (_COUNT) included in BaseColumns for your projection

2- To do a rawQuery using SELECT COUNT(*)

Comment: @mobibob : a/ there is no guarantee that your contentprovider is backed by a sql datababase b/ a cursor is especially made to not allocate the memory for all the records.

Comment: @m3n0R : `With cursor.getCount() you can not assure that it returns the real number of items returned`. what ?

Comment: cursor.getCount() iterates all the cursor data, so it's a big problem of efficiency. Moreover, if you're working with a huge amount of data, it's probably the iterator gets crazy and return random number of rows...

Comment: @njzk2 very good point about the SQL backing -- but I am quite certain that the cursor's getCount does perform the query to get the count.  I recall that was my problem that led me to find this question.  (A long time ago:)

Comment: @m3n0R : disagree, and totally disagree. unless you have source to back that argument ? I really don't see how getCount could return a random number without a very explicit notice in the documentation, at least.

Comment: @njzk2 have you tryied to work with huge amount of data? If not, do it and then check getCount() again ^^. I'm not a kind of pro, I'm just talking about my experiences :-)

Comment: depends what you mean by huge. I have used sqlite storage with 10000+ rows in a table, displaying the getCount using a contentobserver while inserting and updating rows in an underlying service without ever observing any error as to the number of rows actually present.

Answer (score 127):

If you are using contentProvider then you have to do it like **`count(*) AS count`**.

If you use `cursor.getCount()`, that would not be as efficient as the above approach. With `cursor.getCount()` you are fetching all the records just to get counts. The entire code should look like following -

```
 Cursor countCursor = getContentResolver().query(CONTENT_URI,
                new String[] {"count(*) AS count"},
                null,
                null,
                null);

        countCursor.moveToFirst();
        int count = countCursor.getInt(0);
```

The reason why this works is because android needs a column name to be defined.

Comment: there is no guarantee that your contentprovider is backed by a sql datababase.

Comment: is UserDictionary.Words backed by a sql database?

Comment: Currently this is not working: "Invalid column count(*) AS count"

Comment: `count(*) ` is no longer supported in. `Android Q`

Comment: @NileshDeokar what is the alternative for API > =Q?

Comment: well While I was working on that project, I couldn't find any alternative option.

Comment: This doesn't work on Android 10 (at least with `MediaStore.Audio.Playlists`)

Answer (score 4):

I had a similiar problem and found this worked for me.  In the example below I wanted to get the count of images from the MediaStore provider.

```
        final String[] imageCountProjection = new String[] {
                "count(" + MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID + ")",
        };

        Cursor countCursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                imageCountProjection,
                null,
                null,
                null);

        countCursor.moveToFirst();
        int existingImageCount = countCursor.getInt(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

With `cursor.getCount()` you can not assure that it returns the real number of items returned. There are much better ways:

1- If you are using Content Providers, you can do a query and use the `Column (_COUNT)` included in BaseColumns for your projection

```
@Override
public Cursor query(SQLiteDatabase db, Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    ...

    projection = new String[] {
        ContentContract.NotificationCursor.NotificationColumns._COUNT,
    };

    ...

    Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, sortOrder);
    return cursor;
}
```

2- To do a rawQuery using `SELECT COUNT(*)` as @saurabh says in his response.