# A faster way of getting unread SMS count?

Tags: java, android

```
String address = 0123456789;

Cursor unreadcountcursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"),
new String[]{}, "read = 0 and address='"+address+"'", null, null);

int count = unreadcountcursor.getCount();
```

Isn't there a faster way of getting it? Because this code is very heavy to execute when you have to take the count for many numbers, it takes a lot of time to load. Is there another way, supposing that this code will be  in a while loop. I know that using this in the adapter is faster and possible, but the problem with the adapter is that I have to scroll trough the list and return for the count to get updated and notifyDataSetChanged() doesn't do anything for this.

What would be the best solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure this will spare much of device time, but of yours - definitly:

```
 Cursor countCursor = getContentResolver().query(CONTENT_URI,
                "count(*) AS count",
                null,
                null,
                null);

        countCursor.moveToFirst();
        int count = countCursor.getInt(0);
```

cited from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468211/how-do-i-get-the-count-in-my-content-provider)

Comment: No, the question sounded interesting, I was sure that there could be a query with counting and I really found it on the net. That's all.